# Why are table constructors considered "expressions"?

Tags: lua

It would seem on the surface that variable assignment and table constructors do a similar thing.  Why then are table constructors considered 'expressions' while variable assignments are considered 'statements'?

Comment: Are you talking about the "variable assignments" *within* the table (which aren't actual variable assignments), or are you talking about actual variable assignments?

Comment: variable assignments in general

Answer (score 6, accepted):

[Table constructors](http://www.lua.org/pil/3.6.html) evaluate to tables<sup>1</sup>

The "assignments" (`=` symbols) inside a table constructor are merely the syntax used to initialize fields in the table - they are *not* variable assignments. The syntax looks similar with the `=`, but that is only a superficial similarity: do not confuse the two *different* syntax constructs.

Consider if Lua used the same syntax as JavaScript, then it would be

```
t = {x: 2}   -- invalid syntax, for argument
```

and it would be "clear" that `x: 2` is *not* a variable assignment but a field initializer. Of course, Lua syntax dictates that it is written as `t = {x = 2}`, but the distinction idea holds. There are two *different* constructs and the `{x = 2}` table constructor does *not* cause side-effects or variable assignment.

---

<sup>1</sup> It wouldn't make much sense if tables couldn't be assigned for later use! Since only expressions can appears on the right-hand side of an assignment then table constructors must be expressions so the resulting tables (which are values) can be assigned to variables (or passed to functions, etc).

Also note that Lua has [a stronger separation of (assignment) statements and expressions](http://lua-users.org/wiki/StatementsInExpressions) than languages like C.

Comment: The confusion for me lies in the fact that these are actually both statements:

    a = {1};
    a = 1

The table constructor itself: {1} is an expression.  As you usefully pointed out {x = 1} is also considered an expression.  It now makes sense for me, thanks.

Comment: @RossCharette Glad it makes sense :)

Answer (score 3):

If table constructors were not expressions, then you couldn't *assign* them to anything. The statement `variable_name = {}` assigns the result of an expression (in this case, a table constructor) to a variable.

Tables are values, just like numbers, strings, functions, userdata, and everything else in Lua that is a value. Expressions evaluate to values. Thus, the construction of a table is an expression that evaluates to a value.